# Backbone view event not firing - not sure why

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-views

I'm trying to get the `click` event to fire, but it's not working. Maybe someone can see something I can't.

```
ConnectionView = GlobalView.extend({
    tagName: 'div',

    events: {
        "click .social-links": "check"
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();

        this.model.bind("change", this.render);
    },

    render: function() {
        // Compile the template using underscore
        var template = _.template($("#connection-template").html(), this.model.toJSON());

        // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
        $(this.el).html(template);        
    },

    check: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        alert("woot");
    }
});
```

Here is the template that it's pulling:

```
<script id="connection-template" type="text/template">
    <a id="link-<%= alt %>" class="social-links" href="<%= url.replace('||state||', state).replace('||timestamp||', time) %>">add <%= name %></a>
</script>
```

Here is the view that puts the ConnectionView into the DOM:

```
ConnectionsView = GlobalView.extend({
    tagName: 'div',

    initialize: function(){
        this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },

    render: function(){        
        var $connections = $("<div class='external-accounts'>");

        this.collection.each(function (model) {            
            var conn = new ConnectionView({model: model});
            $connections.append(conn.el);
        });

        // Compile the template using underscore
        var template = _.template($("#connections-template").html());
        // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
        $(this.el).html(template({
            connectionsList: $connections.outer()
        }));
    },

    destroy: function() {
        this.constructor.__super__.destroy.apply(this);

    }
});
```

Comment: Where is the code that inserts `ConnectionView`'s `el` into DOM?

Comment: I updated the question with that.

Comment: `.outer` is a custom method I added to jQuery - it just creates a `<div>` wrapper and grabs the `.html` from that. Reason I did this, was because .html only grabbed what was within the current element, but not the whole thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is how you're filling in your `ConnectionsView`'s `el`. You're doing this:

```
// Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
$(this.el).html(template({
    connectionsList: $connections.outer()
}));
```

I have no idea what `.outer()` is all about but it doesn't matter that much. The important thing is that everything is going through the compiled Underscore `template()` function and that means that everything will end up getting converted to strings along the way into the page. Once your DOM elements in `$connections` are in a string, the event bindings are lost and nothing works anymore.

Consider this example:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4tjTm/

In there we do this:

```
var $connections = $('<div>');
var conn = new ConnectionView({ model: m });
$connections.append(conn.el);

var template = _.template('<%= connectionsList %>');
$('#view-goes-here').append(template({
    connectionsList: $connections.html()
}));
```

to add your `ConnectionView` to the page. The events don't work in there because `template()` returns a string and that string gets parsed into DOM elements which end up in the page. But, if we add the `$connections` straight to the page:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/AKkCJ/

using something like this:

```
var $connections = $('<div>');
var conn = new ConnectionView({ model: m });
$connections.append(conn.el);
$('#view-goes-here').append($connections);
```

the events work as expected.

So now we know what went wrong. But how do we fix it? All we need to do is adjust your `ConnectionsView` to add `$connections` directly to the DOM with something like this:

```
render: function() {
    // Move <div class='external-accounts'> into your #connections-template.
    var template = _.template($("#connections-template").html());
    this.$el.html(template());
    var $external = this.$el.find('.external-accounts');
    this.collection.each(function (model) {
        var conn = new ConnectionView({model: model});
        $external.append(conn.el);
    });
    return this; // This is conventional
}
```

Push the `<div class="external-accounts">` into the `ConnectionsView` template and insert the `ConnectionView`s directly into it. This way you're always working with DOM elements, strings don't know about events but DOM elements do.